# Controller spec: expect(controller).to receive(:create) prevents the #create action from being executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, mocking

I have the following action:

```
def create
  binding.pry
  @finding.save
  respond_with @project, @finding
end
```

When running the following test...

```
it 'balances the consecutive numbers', focus: true do
  expect {
    post :create, params: {...}
  }.to change { Finding.count }.from(0).to 1
end
```

...I first have the `binding.pry` console displayed (proving that the `#create` action actually was executed), and then the spec passes:

```
Finished in 4.24 seconds (files took 5.31 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Now when I add an `expect(controller).to receive(:create)`...

```
it 'balances the consecutive numbers', focus: true do
  expect(controller).to receive(:create) # This is new!

  expect {
    post :create, params: {...}}
  }.to change { Finding.count }.from(0).to 1
end
```

...and run the test again, I immediately have this spec failure result shown:

```
expected result to have changed from 0 to 1, but did not change
```

When removing the `change { ... }` expectation...

```
it 'balances the consecutive numbers', focus: true do
  expect(controller).to receive(:create)

  post :create, params: {project_id: @project.id, finding: {requirement_id: @requirement.id}}
end
```

...it passes again:

```
1 example, 0 failures
```

But still, `binding.pry` in `#create` isn't called!

So what's going on here? Somehow `expect(controller).to receive(:create)` seems to prevent the actual `#create` action from being executed! This is not what I want. I want it to execute as always.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I face same issue with AR callbacks. I got the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `expect().to receive()` the real method is supressed... It just verify if something was called as expected...

We usually use it when we want test if something we don't control the answer or we want mock the answer was called.

If you want check if something was called, and also run the original, you should use:

```
expect(something).to receive(:some_method).and_call_original
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation